# how to attach a Lua debugger with EmmyLua?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, lua, jetbrains-ide

I would like to use the EmmyLua plugin in IntelliJ: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9768-emmylua

Most important for me is the ability to debug. [Unfortunately the docs are in chinese](https://emmylua.github.io/run/attach.html) (well at least google translate recognizes the characters as chinese).

How do I attach a debugger?

(please don't recommend alternative tools. I have ZeroBrane up and running on a different PC, it works quite nicely. But on this machine, the choice of software is constrained)

If possible, I would like to use the same featureset as is exposed with ZeroBrane and mobdebug, e.g. adding breakpoints in code, stepping through the code, inspecting variables.

Comment: Please clarify your issue. There should be "Run -> Attach to Local Process..." option where you could select running process.

Comment: Just FYI: ZeroBrane Studio supports remote debugging (application running on one machine with the IDE running on a different one, even different OS), so it may be something to look into if this configuration is available (https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-remote-debugging).

Comment: @PaulKulchenko is it possible to see metatables in stack window? I know that I can add custom watchers like `getmetatable(sometable)` but sometimes I need to track a lot of them.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf, no, it's not supported currently. I'm curious, how would you display them? Technically, you can overwrite `mobdebug.dump` method with your own one that will take metatables into account and serialize them any way you want, but it would be specific to your app.

Answer (score 0):

I use IntelliJ 2021.1 and EmmyLua plugin 1.3.6. EmmyLua provides the debug configuration `Lua Remote(Mobdebug)` which works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to debug `lua` code, no matter what IDE you are using, you need install `luasocket`, that not comes by default with lua.

The easiest way to do it by lua package managers, I'm using `luarocks`.

In case of MAC OS, you can do it by using `brew` (I will add step with lua install):

```
brew install lua

brew install luarocks

luarocks install luasocket
```

after it, you should be able to attach to lua debug session in IntelliJ without any additional configuration

IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.5, EmmyLua 1.4.9

[image]